# How to give my location naming after sorting values from a column

Tags: c#, wpf, excel, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I am generating an excel output from a text file. i am using C# to make my application. Basically, I am sorting the 4th column in ascending order. But what happens is my last column is not numbering from 1 to  n number..See this please https://imageshack.com/i/exeLuFw3j What i should do for this..

My code snippet:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //opening a folder

    if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        //processing selected text file
        int[] cols = new int[] { 15, 15, 25, 15, 15, 15 };
        string[] strLines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(textBox1.Text);

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        string line = string.Empty;
        string LastComment = string.Empty;
        string CarouselName = enter.Text;
        int iCarousel = 0;
        char seperator = '\t';

        SortedDictionary<string, ExcelData> lstExcel = new SortedDictionary<string, ExcelData>();
        ExcelData fline = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < strLines.Length; i++)
        {
            line = RemoveWhiteSpace(strLines[i]).Trim();
            if (line.Length == 0)
                continue;
            string[] cells = line.Replace("\"", "").Split(seperator);


            if (i > 0)
            {
                //if (cells[1] != LastComment)
                {
                    if (!lstExcel.ContainsKey(cells[1].Replace(" ", "_")))
                    {
                            //replacing some white spaces to underscores 
                        fline = new ExcelData();
                        lstExcel.Add(cells[1].Replace(" ", "_"), fline);
                        fline.Footprint = cells[2].Replace(" ", "_");
                        fline.Comment = cells[1].Replace(" ", "_");

                        iCarousel++;
                        if (iCarousel > 45)
                            iCarousel = 1; //once it reaches number 45 it will go back to number 1
                        LastComment = cells[1];
                        fline.Location = String.Format("{0}:{1}", CarouselName, iCarousel);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        fline = lstExcel[cells[1].Replace(" ", "_")];
                    }
                    fline.SrNo++;
                    fline.Total++;
                }

                if (fline.Designator == null)
                    fline.Designator = new List<string>();
                fline.Designator.Add(cells[0].Replace(" ", "_"));
            }

            //Generating string in string builder
            for (int c = 0; c < cells.Length; c++)
                sb.Append(cells[c].Replace(" ", "_").PadRight(cols[c]));
            if (i == 0)
                sb.Append("Location".PadRight(15));// Here i am adding last column Location
            else
                sb.Append(String.Format("{0}:{1}", CarouselName, iCarousel).PadRight(15));//i am starting the numbering of location here.. The Location will be like "name:1, name:2, name:3.. like this
            sb.Append("\r\n");
        }
        ExportInExcel(lstExcel, @"D:\myExcel.xls");
        System.Windows.Forms.Application.Exit();
    }
}


private void ExportInExcel(SortedDictionary<string, ExcelData> lstData, string excelPath)
{
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlApp;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
    object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

    xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
    xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
    xlWorkSheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

    xlWorkSheet.Cells[2, 1] = "Part List";
    xlWorkSheet.get_Range("A2", "A2").Font.Size = 24; //How you can set the font size
    xlWorkSheet.get_Range("A2", "A2").Font.Bold = true;
    xlWorkSheet.Cells[3, 1] = "Project PN:";
    xlWorkSheet.Cells[4, 1] = "Project Name:";
    xlWorkSheet.Cells[5, 1] = "Variant: ";
    xlWorkSheet.get_Range("A3", "A5").Font.Bold = true; //How you can set the font bold
    xlWorkSheet.Cells[6, 1] = "Report Date: " + DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss tt");
    xlWorkSheet.Cells[7, 1] = "Footprint: " + DateTime.Now.ToString("MMM dd, yyyy");


    int rowStartIndex = 8;

    xlWorkSheet.Cells[rowStartIndex, 1] = "Sr No.";
    xlWorkSheet.Cells[rowStartIndex, 2] = "Total";
    xlWorkSheet.Cells[rowStartIndex, 3] = "Designator";            
    xlWorkSheet.Cells[rowStartIndex, 4] = "MAX PN";
    xlWorkSheet.Cells[rowStartIndex, 5] = "Footprint";
    xlWorkSheet.Cells[rowStartIndex, 6] = "Location";
    xlWorkSheet.get_Range("A" + rowStartIndex.ToString(), "F" + rowStartIndex.ToString()).Font.Bold = true; //How you can set the font bold


    //Format Columns
    xlWorkSheet.get_Range("A1", "A1").EntireColumn.ColumnWidth = 3;
    xlWorkSheet.get_Range("B1", "B1").EntireColumn.ColumnWidth = 3; 
    xlWorkSheet.get_Range("C1", "C1").EntireColumn.ColumnWidth = 25;
    xlWorkSheet.get_Range("D1", "D1").EntireColumn.ColumnWidth = 10;
    xlWorkSheet.get_Range("E1", "E1").EntireColumn.ColumnWidth = 23;
    xlWorkSheet.get_Range("F1", "F1").EntireColumn.ColumnWidth = 10; 

    xlWorkSheet.get_Range("C1", "C1").EntireColumn.WrapText = true;
    xlWorkSheet.get_Range("E1", "E1").EntireColumn.WrapText = true;
    //End

    //Header color


    xlWorkSheet.get_Range("A" + rowStartIndex.ToString(), "F" + rowStartIndex.ToString()).Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(Color.FromArgb(79,129,189));
    Color Odd = Color.FromArgb(219, 229, 241);
    Color even = Color.FromArgb(184, 204, 228);

    int i = rowStartIndex; ;

    foreach (ExcelData xls in lstData.Values)
    {
        i++;
        //i+2 : in Excel file row index is starting from 1. It's not a 0 index based collection
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[i, 1] = (i - rowStartIndex).ToString();
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[i, 2] = xls.Total.ToString();
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[i, 3] = String.Join(",", xls.Designator.ToArray());
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[i, 4] = xls.Comment;
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[i, 5] = xls.Footprint;
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[i, 6] = xls.Location;
        Color c = (i % 2) > 0 ? Odd : even;
        xlWorkSheet.get_Range("A" + i.ToString(), "F" + i.ToString()).Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(c);
    }

    //DrawBorder(xlWorkSheet, "A2", "F" + i.ToString());

    xlWorkBook.SaveAs(excelPath, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
    xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
    xlApp.Quit();

    releaseObject(xlWorkSheet);
    releaseObject(xlWorkBook);
    releaseObject(xlApp);
}
```

Please help out guys!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stacy for that you need to change only two lines

1st line

```
fline.Location = String.Format("{0}:{1}", CarouselName, iCarousel);
```

to

```
fline.Location = CarouselName;
```

we will not applying numbering here.

And the second change is in `ExportInExcel()` method. In the loop we are assigning location to the excel cell.

```
xlWorkSheet.Cells[i, 6] = xls.Location;
```

Now, we just need to append the serial number after `xls.Location` property.

```
xlWorkSheet.Cells[i, 6] = xls.Location + (i - rowStartIndex).ToString();
```

We are deducting `rowStartIndex` from the `i` because the row can be started from any number. Now, It is starting from `8` and we don't need to start the location number from `8`.